# How to download an image from an URI and create a bitmap object from it?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm trying to download image from a website and create bitmap based on that image. It looks like this:

```
    public void test()
    {
            PostWebClient client = new PostWebClient(callback);
            cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            client.cookies = cookieContainer;
            client.download(new Uri("SITE"));
    }

    public void callback(bool error, string res)
    {
            byte[] byteArray = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(res);

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray );
            var tmp = new BitmapImage();
            tmp.SetSource(stream);
    }
```

I receive "Unspecified error" on last line of callback method. Interesting fact is that if I use BitmapImage(new Uri("SITE")) it works well... (I can't do this like that because I want to grab cookies from that URL. The image is an jpg.
PostWebClient class -> http://paste.org/53413

Comment: Does the byteArray have the proper Length? Can you dump the content of the byteArray to a file and the image is there?

Comment: Is there a Image.FromStream in the windows-phone .net version?

Comment: @Pinakin Shah no- that's why i have to create bitmap and use image.source=bitmap

Comment: @Florian Gerhardt I will try to do this...

Comment: GOT IT! I came with similar solution: http://www.nickharris.net/2010/09/asynchronous-image-download-on-windows-phone-7/

Comment: Sounds good, post the complete answer here please.

Comment: It is the same with that difference that I have to change a little bit PostWebClient class that I use. The main thing is that to remember stream downloaded (I have used stream copy to and seek) (previously i have been changing it to stream and than once again to stream :D)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is the simplest code from Bitmap class documentation.

```
  System.Net.WebRequest request = 
        System.Net.WebRequest.Create(
        "http://www.microsoft.com//h/en-us/r/ms_masthead_ltr.gif");
    System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    System.IO.Stream responseStream = 
        response.GetResponseStream();
    Bitmap bitmap2 = new Bitmap(responseStream);
```

[MSDN link for Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is to open a network stream via a [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) instance and pass it to [the constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx) of the [Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    using (Stream s = wc.OpenRead("http://hell.com/leaders/cthulhu.jpg"))
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s))
        {
            bmp.Save("C:\\temp\\octopus.jpg");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting image choice

Answer (score 3):

You can try below code:

```
        private Bitmap LoadPicture(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest wreq;
            HttpWebResponse wresp;
            Stream mystream;
            Bitmap bmp;

            bmp = null;
            mystream = null;
            wresp = null;
            try
            {
                wreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                wreq.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

                wresp = (HttpWebResponse)wreq.GetResponse();

                if ((mystream = wresp.GetResponseStream()) != null)
                    bmp = new Bitmap(mystream);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (mystream != null)
                    mystream.Close();

                if (wresp != null)
                    wresp.Close();
            }
            return (bmp);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
            string url ="http://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo11w.png"
            PictureBox picbox = new PictureBox();
            picbox.Load(url);
            Bitmap bitmapRemote = (Bitmap) picbox.Image;
```

url - internet image , we create new instance object PictureBox, then calling **NOT ASYNC** procedure to load image from url, when image retrieved get image as bitmap.
Also you can use **Threading** to work with form, call load in other thread and pass deleate method to retrieve image when complete .

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?