# How to apply Filter to url load image c#

Tags: c#

I am using this method to load the image to my picturebox:

```
private void asdToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Load(textBox1.Text);
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    }
```

The image is loaded perfectly, but when I apply any filter to the image I get error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

So how can I connect my url loaded image to my filters of image processing like gray, RGB and more...

Comment: "When you apply any filter" Where are you doing that?

Comment: Show the relevant code please.

Comment: in my menu strip i create an gray filter for example it is working well for openfiledialog image load
but i get error when i load it with url

This is my gray filter code:

https://jpst.it/YovG

Comment: This is my whole code Ofir Winegarten
:

https://jpst.it/Yowb

Comment: No, this is not the whole code.

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: This the whole code from the beginning to the end : https://jpst.it/YoD4

Comment: the line who causes the error: 
Bitmap gimage = new Bitmap(img);

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `NullReferenceException`at the line

```
Bitmap gimage = new Bitmap(img);
```

because `img` has not been assigned a value. You need to give it a value when you load a new image, something like:

```
private void asdToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Load(textBox1.Text);
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    img = new Bitmap(textBox1.Text); //Add this line.
}
```

I noticed you already had this line inside `saveToolStripMenuItem_Click`, but not inside `asdToolStripMenuItem_Click`

**Edit**: If you're loading a `bitmap` from a URL, you can't load directly into a `bitmap` object like you would for a pictureBox. Check out [Download image and create bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142634/download-image-and-create-bitmap) to learn how to do it.

Comment: i added this line :  'img = new Bitmap(textBox1.Text);' 
now i get this error: **The given path's format is not supported.**
and the image not loaded already !!
_if i dont add that line the image loaded but the filter not work_

Comment: what's the value of textBox1.Text?

Comment: i use url of img i use this : https://trends.google.com/trends/resources/2327917647-google-icon.png

Comment: see the edit I made to the answer